# De-Link Opportunity Product Schedules from Opportunity Products

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, sales-cloud

I am auto-generating `OpportunityLineItemSchedules` when a `OpportunityLineItem` record is inserted, by calculating monthly revenue based on custom business logic. Sometimes on edge-cases the `OpportunityLineItemSchedule` record Revenue calculation is wrong by marginal amount.

This leads to wrong Opportunity Amount getting populated on `Opportunity` as the `OpportunityLineItemProductSchedule.Revenue` amount rolls up to `OpportunityProduct.TotalPrice` Total Price, and the total price rolls up to `Opportunity.Amount`